# Does a set of vectors spans $\mathbb{R}^n$ if the set is linear combination that gives an infinite amount of solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $a_1,...,a_k$ and $b$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $b \ne 0$, and $a_1,...,a_k$ are different from each other.

Also, suppose the equation $x_1a_1+...+x_ka_k = b$ has an infinite amount of solutions.

Now, assume $k \ge n+1$.

Can we say that the set $\{a_1,...,a_k\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I think the answer is positive. The reason is as follows:

$k \ge n+1$ implies a matrix with more columns than rows. Given that $x_1a_1+...+x_ka_k = b$ has an infinite amount of solutions, we can build a matrix that comprises of this exact linear combination and be sure we'd get an infinite amount of solutions. In that matrix, $b$ represents any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and since we'd get an infinite amount of solutions, it means that any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear combination of $\{a_1,...,a_k\}$, hence $\{a_1,...,a_k\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

However, I'm not sure that I'm right, and in any case it doesn't seem like a well-structured proof to me. So, I'd like to know if I'm right, and if so, how can I build a structured proof out of this?

Comment: Here's the big mistake in your reasoning. $b$ is some *fixed* vector. In fact, if there are solutions for *every* $b$, then you can conclude that $a_1,\dots,a_k$ span $\Bbb R^k$, but then how can you have infinitely many solutions unless $k<n$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, did you write $\mathbb{R}^k$ on purpose, or should it be $\mathbb{R}^n$? If it's indeed on purpose, what's $n$?

Comment: My apology. I meant $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Here is a simple counterexample: let $n=3$, $k=4$, $a_1=(1,0,0)$, $a_2=(0,1,0)$, $a_3=(1,1,0)$, $a_4=(-1,-1,0)$ and $b=(1,0,0)$. Clearly $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\sum_{i=1}^4 x_ia_i=b$ has infinitely many solutions (in fact, $x=(1,0,\lambda,\lambda)$ is a solution for every $\lambda$).

Comment: Can you please explain why these vectors don't span $\mathbb{R}^3$? I thought that the fact we have free variables (and hence infinite solutions), it means that any vector in the field can be represented as a linear combination of $a_1...a_k$. Why isn't that true?

Comment: @HeyJude What linear combination of the four vectors equals $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @amd, none. But what I'd really like to know is where do I get it wrong in my understanding of a span\proving a span? i.e., when I commented: I thought that the fact we have free variables (and hence infinite solutions), it means that any vector in the field can be represented as a linear combination of a1...ak. Why isn't that true?

Comment: @HeyJude Having free variables only means that there are redundant vectors among the set. It says nothing useful about what their span might be, although the _number_ of free variables does. In this example, their span is only two-dimensional. A more extreme example: the single equation $x_1=0$ has an infinite number of solutions in $R^n$ $(n>1)$, but the vector $(1,0,\dots,0)$ obviously doesn’t span the enclosing space.

Comment: @amd, thanks. I guess I'm missing a fundamental point here, but why $x_1=0$ has an infinite number of solutions? it's...just what it is, is it? just a single solution.

Comment: @HeyJude Every vector with a first coordinate equal to zero is a solution. The equation doesn’t constrain any of the other coordinates.